# How do I select between GSL Lite and Microsoft GSL in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

I'm writing some C++ code which uses, say, `gsl::span`. Now, I would like to be able to use either [Microsoft/Neil Macintosh's GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL), or Martin Moene's [GSL Lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite). How would I best accomplish that, using CMake as my built system?

Comment: Please describe how you use GSL and GSL Lite when just one is used in your project. Without knowing that, I would guess you have to adjust the path where CMake will look for GSL and re-configure (re-run CMake) for every switch you want to perform.

Comment: @usr1234567: I don't understand the comment. Indeed, just one is used in my project, but I want to not include the GSL headers, I want to look for them on the system and be willing to accept either.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have `#include <gsl-lite/gsl.h>`...

Comment: Then write your own FindGSL.cmake (actually, the name is already taken) which tries to find the includes (find_file) gsl.h and add the prefix gsl-lite.